# Dynamically Bind Style to a StackPanel in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, datatrigger, stackpanel

I have a `ListBox` that contains a `StackPanel` with elements for binding. Based on a value, for instance 'Overdue' = true, the style of the `StackPanel` and a few elements below should change. The only difference between each item is the background of the `StackPanel` and the Foreground of two `TextBlock`s would change. I thought about creating a separate template for each, but with 20 options, that seems like overkill. I have a `SolidColorBrush` setup for each of the 20 items.

I thought I could use a DataTrigger, but I read somewhere that they are not supported in WP7 as WP7 supports Silverlight 3 and greater.

I'm looking for suggestions. I apologize that this may seem to be too subjective and hope someone has the best practice for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a ValueConverter that return SolidColorBrush based on the item's DataContext.

Take a look at Tim's blog, for code sample and detailed explanation.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx

Hope this helps.

Code From Home Dev